# Android change sensor driver implementation

Tags: android, mobile, mocking, driver, sensors

Is there a way to change the sensors driver implementation (binaries/libs) on an Android device without building the whole kernel? The idea is to change a specific driver data feed (for example acceleration) with a mocked data feed on a wide range of devices.

Comment: Android OS has monolithic kernel, so answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by refactoring your code to avoid close-coupling with the real system classes.

If you hide the system classes behind a façade layer, you can then mock this in your tests and supply whatever values you'd like.

In addition to solving this problem, it's also a good architectural pattern to use in general.